# Problema para recuperar o UID da Autenticação do firebase?

Tags: flutter, dart

Pessoal estou tentando criar uma coleção no Firebase e para o documento dessa coleção gostaria de pegar o UID da autenticação do cadastro de usuário, o cadastro da autenticação está ok porém não cria a coleção segue o código abaixo:

o Código que comunica com Firebase

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:scoped_model/scoped_model.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class UserModel extends Model{

  FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

  FirebaseUser firebaseUser;
  Map<String, dynamic> userData = Map();

  bool isLoading = false;

  void signUp({@required Map<String, dynamic> userData, @required String pass, @required VoidCallback onSuccess, @required VoidCallback onFail}){
    isLoading = true;
    notifyListeners();

    _auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
        email: userData["email"],
        password: pass
    ).then((user) async{
      AuthResult firebaseUser = user;

      await _saveUserData(userData);

      onSuccess();
      isLoading = false;
      notifyListeners();
    }).catchError((e) async{
      onFail();
      isLoading = false;
      notifyListeners();
      print("erro");
    });
  }

  void signIn() async{
    isLoading = true;
    notifyListeners();

    await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 3));

    isLoading = false;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  void recoverPass(){

  }

  Future<Null> _saveUserData(Map<String, dynamic> userData) async{
    this.userData = userData;
    print("teste $userData");
    await Firestore.instance.collection("users").document(firebaseUser.uid).setData(userData);
  }
}
```

o Código da View do Formulário de cadastro

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:loja_virtual/models/user_model.dart';
import 'package:scoped_model/scoped_model.dart';

class SignUpScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SignUpScreenState createState() => _SignUpScreenState();
}

class _SignUpScreenState extends State<SignUpScreen> {
  final _nameController = TextEditingController();
  final _emailController = TextEditingController();
  final _passController = TextEditingController();
  final _addressController = TextEditingController();

  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("Criar Conta"),
          centerTitle: true,
        ),
        body: ScopedModelDescendant<UserModel>(
          builder: (context, child, model) {
            if (model.isLoading) {
              return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
            } else {
              return Form(
                key: _formKey,
                child: ListView(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                  children: <Widget>[
                    TextFormField(
                      controller: _nameController,
                      decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: "Nome Completo"),
                      validator: (text) {
                        if (text.isEmpty) {
                          return "Nome Inválido!";
                        }
                      },
                    ),
                    SizedBox(height: 16.0),
                    TextFormField(
                      controller: _emailController,
                      decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: "E-mail"),
                      keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
                      validator: (text) {
                        if (text.isEmpty || !text.contains("@")) {
                          return "E-mail inválido!";
                        }
                      },
                    ),
                    SizedBox(height: 16.0),
                    TextFormField(
                      controller: _passController,
                      decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: "Senha"),
                      obscureText: true,
                      validator: (text) {
                        if (text.isEmpty || text.length < 6) {
                          return "Senha Inválida!";
                        }
                      },
                    ),
                    SizedBox(height: 16.0),
                    TextFormField(
                      controller: _addressController,
                      decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: "Endereço"),
                      validator: (text) {
                        if (text.isEmpty) {
                          return "Senha Inválido!";
                        }
                      },
                    ),
                    SizedBox(height: 16.0),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 44.0,
                      child: RaisedButton(
                          child: Text(
                            "Criar Conta",
                            style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 18.0,
                            ),
                          ),
                          textColor: Colors.white,
                          color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                          onPressed: () {
                            if (_formKey.currentState.validate()) {

                              Map<String, dynamic> userData = {
                                "name": _nameController.text,
                                "email": _emailController.text,
                                "address": _addressController.text
                              };

                              model.signUp(
                                  userData: userData,
                                  pass: _passController.text,
                                  onSuccess: _onSuccess,
                                  onFail: _onFail
                              );
                            }
                          }),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              );
            }
          },
        ));
  }

  void _onSuccess() {}

  void _onFail() {}
}
```

analisei que o problema está no código abaixo:

```
Firestore.instance.collection("users").document(firebaseUser.uid).setData(userData);
```

especificamente na variável firebaseUser.uid onde printando na tela me retorna o erro abaixo:

> E/flutter (  916): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(157)]
>   Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: The getter 'uid' was called on
>   null. E/flutter (  916): Receiver: null E/flutter (  916): Tried
>   calling: uid E/flutter (  916): #0      Object.noSuchMethod
>   (dart:core-patch/object_patch.dart:53:5)

alguém pode me ajudar?

Answer (score 0):

Você não está carregando a variável `FirebaseUser firebaseUser`, por isso o problema...

Crie o seguinte método

```
  Future<Void> currentUserUID() async {
    firebaseUser = await _firebaseAuth.currentUser();
  }
```

E antes de chamar o `_saveUserData` faça

```
  void signUp({@required Map<String, dynamic> userData, @required String pass, @required VoidCallback onSuccess, @required VoidCallback onFail}){
    isLoading = true;
    notifyListeners();

    _auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
        email: userData["email"],
        password: pass
    ).then((user) async{
      AuthResult firebaseUser = user;

      await currentUserUID();
      await _saveUserData(userData);

      onSuccess();
      isLoading = false;
      notifyListeners();
    }).catchError((e) async{
      onFail();
      isLoading = false;
      notifyListeners();
      print("erro");
    });
  }
```

Dessa forma sua variável irá receber os dados necessário para serem utilizados depois.

Se você quiser dar uma olhada, em um dos meus projetos exemplos criei uma classe de conexão com o firebase, [essa aqui](https://github.com/matheusrmribeiro/EquipmentMaintenance/blob/master/lib/api/firebaseConnection.dart).

Comment: Matheus era isso mesmo, fiz o que você falou e deu certo, muito obrigado pela ajuda.

Comment: Por nada carinha, depois não se esqueça de marcar a minha resposta como aceita, isso ajuda quem vier em busca de soluções parecidas.